# Align text and space evenly

Tags: text, html-table, alignment, spacing

I need help if you go to my home page here http://jaboostudios.com/ you can see at the bottom I have set up a table with images at the top with simple roll over behaviors and text below it. What has been driving me batty is why the text is slightly off and not lined up correctly. I also want the text to be even in width so that the images and text will fit perfectly balanced on screen. Make sense? Any help would be greatly appreciated! HTML table code below ...

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<table cellspacing="5">
<table cellpadding="15">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">

<div><img class="size-full wp-image-1430" onmouseover="this.src=' http://jaboostudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/artbuttonrollover.jpg '" onmouseout="this.src=' http://jaboostudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/artbutton.jpg '" alt="artbutton" src="http://jaboostudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/artbutton.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></div></td>
<td><img class="size-full wp-image-1430 aligncenter" onmouseover="this.src=' http://jaboostudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/brandingbuttonrollover.jpg '" onmouseout="this.src=' http://jaboostudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/brandingbutton.jpg '" alt="brandingbutton" src="http://jaboostudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/brandingbutton.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></td>
<td><img class="size-full wp-image-1430 aligncenter" onmouseover="this.src=' http://jaboostudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/webbuttonrollover.jpg '" onmouseout="this.src=' http://jaboostudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/webbutton.jpg '" alt="webbutton" src="http://jaboostudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/webbutton.jpg" width="200" height="200" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<h1>ART</h1>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<h1>BRANDING</h1>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<h1>WEB</h1>
</td>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: justify;">
<h5>Artist Jesse Lewis, of Jaboo Studios, offers a diverse array of artwork. Jesse has primarily created artwork for pet lovers and is known throughout Connecticut for his pet portrait work. He also has many collectors and clients in the field of real estate. Jesse creates one-of-a-kind artwork from recycled materials using acrylic paint on canvas or wood. He uses a combination of techniques, borrowing from street art, pop art, and outsider art. He has a style that is unique, blending these influences. This artwork makes great gifts for the holiday seasons or to add to the decor of any home or office. 

Want to talk to Jesse about a project or work of art? You can reach him by phone or email to discuss your project. Feel free to reach out.

P. 203.763.9154 
E. Contact@JabooStudios.com  
</h5>
</td>
<td style="text-align: justify;">
<h5>Graphic designer, Jesse Lewis, can help a new start up business or individual with their corporate identity. Jesse specializes in logo design, however a logo is not all you need to get your new venture off the ground. He is available to do it all. Logos, business cards, letterheads, and any other graphic design needs. He has created flyers and ads for many local businesses. He would love to work with you and help you on your journey to success. He offers free initial consultation over the phone and his rate is seventy-five dollars an hour to meet and discuss projects in detail. Designing is a process and takes a relationship between the client and the designer. Establishing trust and understanding is the first step to getting great results. 

Want to talk to Jesse about a graphic design need? You can reach him by phone or email to discuss your project. Feel free to reach out.

P. 203.763.9154 
E. Contact@JabooStudios.com  
</h5>
</td>
<td style="text-align: justify;">
<h5>A website can be an overwhelming process. Jesse is here to help you every step of the way, from getting your domain name and hosting, to design and launch of your site.  Web designer, Jesse Lewis, has built many websites for local Connecticut businesses and start-ups.  Jesse now works in the content management platform and designs with Wordpress. He has found over the years that Wordpress has many great capabilities and their plugin features make site design limitless. Jesse has also created sites using the Dreamweaver platform. He now prefers Wordpress and would encourage you to do the same. Jesse uses Go Daddy to register domain names and hosting. If you do not know how to set up your hosting or domain name on your own, Jesse can help you with setup as well. 

Want to talk to Jesse about a website design project? You can reach him by phone or email to discuss your project. Feel free to reach out.

P. 203.763.9154 
E. Contact@JabooStudios.com  
</h5>
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved my own issue. The problem was in the td style. My width was set to 100% so I made the td width 33.3% with valign="top">. Now it looks how I want!!! So happy to have this solved was driving me nuts and took two days but happy I figured it out on my own! YAY!